# How to separate and sort a list of integers and it's associated string?

Tags: python, sorting

If I have this:

```
[(3, 'it'), (0, 'my'), (2, 'ate'), (1, 'cat')]
```

How can I separate the integer from the string and then sort it to get this result:

```
0 'my'
1 'cat'
2 'ate'
3 'it'
```

Comment: What do you mean by separate? Print it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
l = [(3, 'it'), (0, 'my'), (2, 'ate'), (1, 'cat')]

for item in sorted(l):
    print("{} '{}'".format(item[0], item[1]))
```

**Output:**

```
0 'my'
1 'cat'
2 'ate'
3 'it'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    x = sorted([(3, 'it'), (0, 'my'), (2, 'ate'), (1, 'cat')])
    for i in x:
       print(i)
```

output:

```
(0, 'my')
(1, 'cat')
(2, 'ate')
(3, 'it')
```

Comment: Why not unpack the tuple if you are already printing it out ?

Answer (score 0):

Pythonic way, [how sorting](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html), `itemgetter` from documentation: "return a callable object that fetches item"

```
L = [(3, 'it'), (0, 'my'), (2, 'ate'), (1, 'cat')]
from operator import itemgetter
print ( "\n".join(map(lambda x: "%d '%s'" % x, sorted(L, key=itemgetter(0)))))
```

you get,

```
0 'my'
1 'cat'
2 'ate'
3 'it'
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply sort the list of tuples, and the print them formatted:

```
>>> tuples = [(3, 'it'), (0, 'my'), (2, 'ate'), (1, 'cat')]
>>> tuples = sorted(tuples)
>>> for tup in tuples:
    print("{} '{}'".format(*tup))


0 'my'
1 'cat'
2 'ate'
3 'it'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to your question on ...  [How can I sort a dictionary by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key)

Using that code, I developed the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# StackOverflow answer sample to question:
# How to separate and sort a list of integers and it's associated string?
# Author: RJC (aka mmaurice)
# Question input: [(3, 'it'), (0, 'my'), (2, 'ate'), (1, 'cat')]
# Question expected output: 
# 0 'my'
#
# 1 'cat'
#
# 2 'ate'
#
# 3 'it'
import collections
test_dict = dict([(3, 'it'), (0, 'my'), (2, 'ate'), (1, 'cat')])
print(test_dict) #not in order
#use collections to sort the dictionary.
od_test_dict = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(test_dict.items()))
for k, v in od_test_dict.items(): print(k, v)
```

Hope this helps